# How to height of span without expanding the page?

Tags: html, css

So I made an animation of a so called "starfield".
They are made of a couple of small, rotating, radial gradients.

Now when they rotate, you can clearly see where they stop/end. Increasing the height of the background fixes this, but it also increases the entire page height.

Is there anyway to increase the background height, but keep it centered in the page?

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/twanmulder/pen/GNLRWo

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="starfield">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` on `.starfield` and `overflow: hidden` on `body` (or the parent of `.starfield`).

```css
body, html {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.starfield {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 15s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
     -moz-animation: fadein 15s; /* Firefox < 16 */
      -ms-animation: fadein 15s; /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-animation: fadein 15s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
          animation: fadein 15s;
}

.starfield > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.starfield > * {
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 60px, #ccc, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 50px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   radial-gradient(2px 2px at 30px 100px, #eee, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   radial-gradient(2px 2px at 40px 60px, #fff, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   radial-gradient(2px 2px at 110px 90px, #ccc, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   radial-gradient(2px 2px at 190px 150px, #ddd, rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.starfield > * {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: starfieldRotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  .starfield > *:nth-child(1){
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-delay: -15;
  }
  .starfield > *:nth-child(2){
    animation-duration: 35s;
    animation-delay: -50s;
  }
  .starfield > *:nth-child(3){
    animation-duration: 50s;
  }
  .starfield > *:nth-child(4){
    animation-duration: 70s;
  }
  .starfield > *:nth-child(5){
    animation-duration: 120s;
  }

@keyframes starfieldRotate {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="starfield">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me!